# Difficulty in finding the norm of addition and substraction of two functions in set

Tags: functional-analysis

The "parallelogram identity" is
$$
\|x+y\|^2+\|x-y\|^2=2\big(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\big).
$$
The supremum norm  of $C[0,1]$ does not satisfy such an identity: for $f=1$ and $g=x$,
$$
\|f\|=1,\,\,\|g\|=1,\,\,\|f+g\|=2,\,\,\|f-g\|=1,
$$
and hence
$$
5=\|f+g\|^2+\|f-g\|^2\ne2\big(\|f\|^2+\|g\|^2\big)=4.
$$ 
This is previously discussed question here. But as I am unable to evaluate how $$
\|f\|=1,\,\,\|g\|=1,\,\,\|f+g\|=2,\,\,\|f-g\|=1$$, 
what property of supremum is used here to evaluate norm of addition and substraction of two functions. Please anyone show me the steps involved here.

Comment: Try drawing the graphs of $f+g$ and $f-g$, then see if you can come up with a proof.

Comment: $1+x \le 2$ and $1-x \le 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Here inequalities are involved but finally we should get equation with "equal to "sign. So how?

Comment: @Aweygan Sorry I need not graphical interpretation here